# Proving intersections with the Archimedean property

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

**Problems:**

> Find the following intersection and union. Prove your claims
>
> a)  Intersection of the sets $\big{(}0,\frac{1}n \big{)}$ where $n$ is indexed over the set of Natural numbers
>
> b) Union of the sets $\big{[}\frac{1}n,3-\frac{1}n\big{]}$ where $n$ is indexed over the set of Natural numbers

**My issues:**

**$\bf Q1$** Hi can someone explain why ($a$) is empty instead of a set with point $0$.

I did my interpretation as following, not sure is true or not :
If it’s $[0,1/n]$, then we say the interval is a point with $0$ by the definition of degenerate interval $[0,0]$.

$\bf  Q2$ Please explain why ($b$) is $(0,3)$ instead of $[0,3]$ and which concept should I review ?

$\bf  Q3$ When solving real analysis problems, I often missed some detailed ideas like $Q1$ & $Q2$ in class. I tried to pick the missing ideas from available resources, but most resources doesn't  contain detailed explanation about the steps on finishing prove.

Please give some advice how to overcome this issue.

Thank you

Comment: [Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34121/42969). Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2):

I will tackle the two computational problems presented.

- **Question $4a$ is the empty set.**

The reason that {$0$} is not the answer is because in order for {$0$} to be in the intersection of the sets, it needs to be an element of *every* set in question. However, if we take the example of when $n=5$, we note that this interval does **not** contain 0 since it is an open interval from $(0,\frac{1}5)$. If the set had been $[0,\frac{1}5]$, then you would be correct, however since the interval is open, this means that $0$ is not in the intersection.

- **Question $4b$ is $(0,3)$**

The reason that $[0,3]$ is not the correct answer is that there is no set containing the point $0$ or $3$. In order for $0$ and $3$ to be an element of the union, we need it to be the case that $0$ and $3$ are elements of at least one of the sets. However, even as $n\rightarrow \infty$, we get the set $[\frac{1}n, 3-\frac{1}n]$ = $(0,3)$ since the term $\frac{1}n$ converges to $0$, but only as $n\rightarrow \infty$. Since $n$ is a natural number, we note that this interval gets closer and closer to the set $[0,3]$ but never actually reaches the point $0$ or $3$ as these are only achieved in the limit and not for any actual natural number.